# Old alarms cancellation

Tags: android

At `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity`,  I've scheduled three repeating alarms that go off at different times of the day. 
from the `BroadcastReceiver` class I launch the desired services.
 
My question is…  from where can I cancel the old alarms?  does it to be at the `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity`,  at the `BroadcastReceiver` class,  or at the service class? 
thank you in advance…

Comment: It depends upon your need . Doing in `oncreate()` makes it up to user, Cause for this your app needs to open.

Comment: thank you for the answaer ADM …  now,  if I want to cancel them without opening the app..  where the cancellations need to be called?

Comment: Probably in `BroadcastReceiver` . I am not sure of it cause i do not exactly now the flow of your app .

Comment: thank you ADM, and I hope that someone give a precise answer.